# sentence structure of 'That is what I believe it means'

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-pronouns

> That is what I believe it means

Is 'what' here the object of 'I believe'? Or is there a wh-word omitted?

Comment: There's nothing missing. In such contexts, ***what*** serves as a "noun" all on its own - equivalent to ***the thing that/which** [I think]*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at how questions are formed with phrases like *I think*, *I believe*, etc. Here's what Swan's *Practical English Usage* (Unit 264.8) says about it:

> A *wh*-question usually refers to the main clause which starts with the question word. However, questions can also refer to subordinate *that*-clauses after verbs like *wish*, *think* or *say*.
>
> *Who do you wish **(that) you'd married**, then?
>
>   How long do you think **(that) we should** wait?
>
>   What did you say **(that) you wanted** for Christmas?*
>
> *That* is usually dropped in cases like these; it must be dropped when the question word refers to the subject of the subordinate clause.
>
> ***Who*** do you think **is outside**? (NOT <strike>Who-do-you think that is outside?</strike>)
>   **What** do you suppose **will happen now**? (NOT <strike>What do you suppose that will happen now?</strike>)

---

In other words, let's take this statement:

> He thinks (that) you'll have to wash the dishes.

To turn it into a *wh*-question, you'll have to change the verb *think* and put the question word before it, even if you're asking about something after it:

> **What does** he **think** (that) you'll have to do?

To form an indirect question, remove the auxiliary *do* and put the verb into the tense of the auxiliary:

> What **does** he **think** (that) you'll have to do?
>   What he **thinks** (that) you'll have to do.
>
> How long **do** you **think** (that) we should wait?
>   How long you **think** (that) we should wait.
>
> What **did** you **say** (that) you wanted for Christmas?
>   What you **said** (that) you wanted for Christmas.

The second example in each pair can't be used on its own, but it can be used as a subordinate clause. Subordinate clauses of this type can function as objects of verbs. For example:

> I **told** him *what you said (that) you wanted for Christmas*.
>
> He **said** *how long he thought we should wait*.

---

In your example, the verb is *is*.

> That **is** *what I believe (that) it means*.

As *PEU* says, a *wh*-expression can refer to the clause right after *think*, *believe*, etc. Therefore, the *what* in your sentence refers to *it means*, not *I believe*.

Answer (score 0):

No, 'what' is an object of the verb 'mean' in the sentence.